# Google Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol: unable to get function scope

Tags: google-chrome, remote-debugging

I write custom debugger for Google Chrome using [Remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index). My debugger works fine, except for it can't access function scope. I listen for `Debugger.paused` event and listener gets array of `CallFrame`s. I get `closure` scope from each frame and so I can get all bound variables with their properties. There are functions among these variables. I post `Runtime.getProperties` with id of one of the functions to Chrome and get its properties. And here is what I get in response:

```
{  
  "result":[  
      {  
        "configurable":false, "enumerable":false,
        "isOwn":true, "name":"length",
        "value":{  
            "description":"0",
            "type":"number",
            "value":0
        },
        "writable":false
      }, {  
        "configurable":false, "enumerable":false,
        "isOwn":true, "name":"name",
        "value":{  
            "type":"string",
            "value":""
        },
        "writable":false
      }, {  
        "configurable":false, "enumerable":false,
        "get":{  
            "className":"Function",
            "description":"function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }",
            "objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":34}",
            "type":"function"
        },
        "isOwn":true,"name":"arguments",
        "set":{  
            "className":"Function",
            "description":"function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }",
            "objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":35}",
            "type":"function"
        }
      }, {  
        "configurable":false, "enumerable":false,
        "get":{  
            "className":"Function",
            "description":"function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }",
            "objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":36}",
            "type":"function"
        },
        "isOwn":true, "name":"caller",
        "set":{  
            "className":"Function",
            "description":"function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }",
            "objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":37}",
            "type":"function"
        }
      }, {  
        "configurable":false, "enumerable":false,
        "isOwn":true, "name":"prototype",
        "value":{  
            "className":"Object",
            "description":"Object",
            "objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":38}",
            "type":"object"
        },
        "writable":true
      }, {  
        "configurable":true, "enumerable":false,
        "isOwn":true, "name":"__proto__",
        "value":{  
            "className":"Function",
            "description":"function Empty() {}",
            "objectId":"{\"injectedScriptId\":3,\"id\":39}",
            "type":"function"
        },
        "writable":true
      }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there is no `<function scope>` property. However, when I debug the same code and stop at the same location, I can open `Closure` -> `$return` -> `<function scope>`. I really need this, as $return is callback that contains bound variables in its scope, so moving through callback closure chain I can rebuild stack trace.